# Can't move page file to external SD-card

Tags: windows-8.1, sd-card, tablet, pagefile

Recently I got a windows 8.1 tablet, but it has very low internal memory (16GB). It has extendable memory via an SD card (I put in 64GB) and I tried moving page file to it, but after setting no page file on C drive and system managed on D and restarting tablet I get the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVmv6.png). So, is it even possible to move the page file this way?

[image]

Comment: It sounds at the time Windows attempts to create the page file, your external storage isn't available, if that's the case there might not be a great deal you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### About the problem.

I think that Windows tries to attach the pagefile before it initializes SD card reader's driver. That makes pagefile unavailable at this time, so Windows creates a temporary one. This issue is unsolvable.

#### Is it a problem?

No, I don't think so. While hard disks are few orders of magnitude slower than RAM, SD cards are even slower. It means that your system would become really sluggish as soon as it starts paging, ie. when it's low on RAM - and you don't want that.

Moreover, SD cards have lifetime limited by number of writes. It's usually not a problem when they are used for file storage, but paging would kill a card very quickly, probably within few months at best.

Use SD card for storage and internal memory for paging, not the other way.

Comment: Is it the same with installing programs to SD-card? Because including page file I have only 1GB in main drive to work with.

Comment: Programs are loaded only when you start them, optionally loading additional components later, so performance probably won't be affected that much if you install them on SD card instead of internal memory. To save more space consider moving your Documents folders to external storage. You could also move browser caches, Temp folders etc. using symlinks or junctions (AFAIR it was explained here on SU, but if you can't find it, just ask. Someone will answer or mark it as a duplicate with a link to the original question)